# Do I need to add my Google Analytics tracking code to each page of my html website

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, tracking

My website is pure html and each page have separate header. So, Do I need to add google analytic tracking code only in index.html or else in all the pages?

Comment: Every page that you want to track needs to have the tracking code.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo, Its working